# UITabBarController seems to open one view before closing another

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, uitabbarcontroller

I have a method that is called when a Settings button is tapped in my root view, that subclasses two UIViewControllers, attaches them to a UITabBarController and pushes the UITabBarController onto a navigation stack:

```
-(IBAction)onSettings:(id)sender {
// Create the Settings Views
SettingsViewController *vcSettings1 = [[Settings1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings1ViewController" bundle:nil];
Settings2ViewController *vcSettings2 = [[Settings2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings2ViewController" bundle:nil];

// Create the Tab View
UITabBarController *tabController= [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabController.viewControllers = @[vcSettings1,vcSettings2];

// Pass the Index of the database on to the views so they can pull the record from the database
vcSettings.recordIndex = recordIndex;
vcSettings2.recordIndex = recordIndex;

// Add the tab bar controller to the navigation stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];
}
```

In each of the Settings views, I override the viewWillAppear method to load a row of data from an sqlite database at primary key recordIndex.  (Both views pull the same record and display different data from the record, except one field is the same on both.)

I also override viewWillDisappear in each view to save the controls data back to the database.

I can verify that every time I switch views using the tab bar, the viewWillDisappear method is called on one closing view and the viewWillAppear is called on the opening view.

The problem is that when I change data on the first view and switch to the second view, the data is not changed on the second view unless I return to the first view and then back to the second.  As best I can tell, here is what seems to be happening:

1. View 1 is open.  I change the data in the field.
2. I tap on the tab for View 2
3. viewWillAppear is called for View 2, populating the field in View 2 with the old data in the database.
4. viewWillDisappear is then called for View 1, saving the changed data to the database.

It seems that the opening view is calling viewWillAppear BEFORE the closing view is calling viewWillDisappear.

I have tried this other ways, such as using a singleton, and simply trying to modify the recordIndex from both views and in all cases it seems that the data is loaded from the opening view before it is saved from the closing view.

Is this a bug in the way UITabBarController works, or am I abusing viewWillAppear and Disappear in a way that I'm not supposed to?  Has anyone else run across this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good design. There is no guarantee that viewWillAppear of new view should be called after viewWillDisappear from the previous one. Even if that were to work, there would be no guarantee that this would keep working in future iOS versions.

If performance is not impacted, a quick fix could be to save the changes to the database as they occur, you would always have an up to date database that could be accessed from any view in any circumstance.

Best design is to have some model classes, with your model objects accessible through a singleton for example. Those model objects are updated real time as you interact with the UI, they are the ones being accessed by the different views, and they are periodically saved using the method of your choice.

Comment: Thanks JP, I like the 'update as changes are made' idea better then what I was doing, and you're right, that seems like it should future proof the app pretty well.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

as a cheap solution you could load data in viewDidAppear but in general I agree with JP's answer